# Printing out list with proper if conditions in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, if-statement, printing

```
k1 = ['UCF', 'Mario', 'JonnnyStorm']
k2 = [10, 14, 5]
k3 = [300, 700, 600]

for p,g,h in zip(k1,k2,k3):
    if k2 > 10 and k3 > 400:
        print p,g,h
```

What I want to see is

Output:

```
Mario 14 700
```

What i get is

Output:

```
UCF 10 300
Mario 14 700
JonnnyStorm 5 600
```

Even when I switch and play with the conditions, I still get totally wrong answers I do not expect. I must be missing something Vital.

Also if I could print it out as

```
Mario has 14 Points and is at Rank 700.
```

That would be great. I tried that to with %s and %d with the normal print syntax and was getting wild errors. If anyone could not only get me an answer but a detailed explanation of what your doing that would be great. I really want to understand why.

Comment: `if g > 10 and h > 400:`

Comment: Think about what you wrote. Does `[10, 14, 5] > 10` make much sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
k1 = ['UCF', 'Mario', 'JonnnyStorm']
k2 = [10, 14, 5]
k3 = [300, 700, 600]

for p,g,h in zip(k1,k2,k3):
    if g > 10 and h > 400:
        print '{0} has {1} points and is at Rank {2}'.format(p, g, h)
```

Your code tests `k2` and `k3` in the conditions, instead of the elements inside them.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are comparing a list to a number, k2 is a list while 10 is a number; so the actual comparison is false and should raise an exception but this is not the case in python. The comparison of the list k2 to the number will always be greater than any number and thus the condition is always true. The soltuion is already posted. 
Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I was wondering. Everyone was saying I was comparing the list and not the elements in the list. But if that was the case then why no error or exception when the comparison is executed. I thought I had it right because i was getting no error and miss understanding something.